# Generating a nuspec path string for profile 158

Tags: nuget

How do I write a nuspec string for profile 158. An example from another profile is

lib\portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid16+MonoTouch40+sl40+wp71_._

**Update.** http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Framework_Names gives some hints of eligible names

perhaps something like:

portable-win+net45+sl5+wp8+MonoAndroid??+MonoTouch??

portable-netcore45+net45+sl5+windowsphone8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10  ??

or maybe

portable-wp8+netcore45+net45+sl5+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a PCL project in Visual Studio for Profile158 and then using **nuget pack** on the project the following folder is added to the NuGet package:

```
portable-win+net45+sl50+wp80
```

Comment: good idea to use nuget pack - on my end it generates portable-win+net45+sl50+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10

Comment: I do not have the Mono PCLs installed which should explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [simple CLI application](https://github.com/protomouse/NuHelper) that allows for automation.

```
C:\> NuHelper.exe shortFrameworkName .NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile136
portable-net40+sl50+wp80+win+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10
```

You can grab a binary of it [here](https://ci.protomou.se/job/NuHelper/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/NuHelper/bin/Release/NuHelper.zip).

Comment: Handy tool! The link to the binary is dead though.